# How to set the order of json properties when sending a Map object

Tags: json, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jackson

I am sending a HashMap object as response from my RestController.

```
@GetMapping("/balance")
    public Map<String, Object>  fetchAccountsByBalance(){
         Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
         response.put("records", totalNumberOfRecords);
         response.put("pages", totalPages);
         response.put("data", pageResponse.getContent());
}
```

How to control the order of JSON properties when returning a Map object?

Comment: Looking at your code, I would suggest, instead of returning a map, you should return an object say Page. And in Page class, define 3 variables records,pages, and data .That is more concise and will maintain order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LinkedHashMap` maintains insertion order:

```
Map<String, Object> response = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```